# Python: How to find literal text that appears in a displayed webpage given that webpage's HTML as text (eBay)

Tags: python, html, parsing, request

I have been using this module:

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

to get the HTML of an eBay listing as text (and storing it in a string).

I then want to search for certain keywords in this string.

The problem is that the text that appears in the listing description DOES NOT APPEAR in that listing's HTML.

For example:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/Converse-All-Star-High-Double-Tongue-Size-5-/221617886213?pt=UK_Women_s_Shoes&hash=item3399749405

I would expect to be able to find:

"comfortable and warm"

somewhere in the listing's HTML because that string appears in the listing's description.

In the other websites I have looked at, all text on the page appears in the HTML. I guess eBay is designed better or something but I know nothing about how HTML works.

Any input is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Its because that data is in an iframe. Its like an inner website. 
If you load the page, the iframe will not be loaded. 
You have to load that manually.

This is the iframe:

```
<iframe id="desc_ifr" class="" height="10000" width="99%" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0" src="http://vi.vipr.ebaydesc.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItemDescV4&amp;item=221617886213&amp;t=1417007358000&amp;tid=310&amp;category=95672&amp;seller=punkyllama26&amp;excSoj=1&amp;excTrk=1&amp;lsite=3&amp;ittenable=false&amp;domain=ebay.com&amp;descgauge=1" title="Seller's description of item"></iframe>
```

This is the link (look at src in iframe) with the data:

http://vi.vipr.ebaydesc.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItemDescV4&item=221617886213&t=1417007358000&tid=310&category=95672&seller=punkyllama26&excSoj=1&excTrk=1&lsite=3&ittenable=false&domain=ebay.com&descgauge=1